# Prevent merged cells splitting between pages

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a program to create a Microsoft Word document from an Oracle table.

The document has tables with the left hand column which represents group field name and the next column has some fields associated with that group.  I don't want the groups to split across pages. My code for doing this doesn't appear to work - the groups are still split across pages.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
'output table data - data gets loaded into the display table starting at row 3
'(row 1 and 2 are the headers)
For row = 3 To maxrows + 2
    Dim dataRow = dsHDTabCols.Tables(0).Rows(row - 3)  'dataset has rows to output
    If dataRow("KEEP_WITH_NEXT_FLAG") & "" = "K" Then
        oTable.Cell(row, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext = True 
    End If
    If dataRow("GROUP_NAME") & "" = "@ditto@" Then 
        VerticalMergeWithPriorRow(oTable, row, 1) 
    Else 
        oTable.Cell(row, 1).Range.Text = dataRow("GROUP_NAME") & "" 
    End If
    oTable.Cell(row, 2).Range.Text = dataRow("COLUMN_NAME") & ""
```

Note that I am vertically merging cells, so I am limited to using the `table.cell` references.

Table.rows(nnn)` gives an exception.

The data processed by the code above starts with a data row with the keep_with_next_flag set to "K", so the code sets the cell paragraph format keepwithnext = true.

The next data row in a group would come with the group name = "@ditto@" and a keep_with_next_flag set to "K".  As above, the code sets the cell paragraph format with keepwithnext = true. Since it's a ditto, the code will execute the VerticalMergeWithPriorRow function which just merges the current cell with the cell in the same column, but prior row.

Comment: I made a change to the code to set the keepwithnext on the first column.  Previously I was setting this on the second column.  Not sure why this was necessary but it works now.  That being said, the paging of the output was not to my liking, so I'm going to try a different approach.

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code for how you are finding Vertical Merged cells? It looks like you created a function, but don't list the code. This would make this question more useful to others.

Comment: Possibly this is a helpful question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874277/prevent-vertically-merged-cells-from-breaking-across-page-automatically